# Dealing with two different values of a property (cloud and default) in cloudfoundry and the @Value annotation

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, properties-file

I am in reference to Spring's `@Value` annotation as documented here: [@Value](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) and Spring profiles.

I need to be able to have different values for a given property such as:

```
websiteContext=http://localhost:8080/kadjoukor
```

...according to whether the app is running locally or on the cloud. I am not sure how to achieve that with the `@Value("${websiteContext}")` annotation...

What is the best practice for dealing with such an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring 3.1 or later, you can take advantage of bean profiles and the CloudFoundry "cloud" profile to load a different properties file depending on the environment. That might look something like this in a Spring XML configuration file:

```
<beans profile="default">
    <context:property-placeholder location="default.properties"/>
</beans>
<beans profile="cloud">
    <context:property-placeholder location="cloud.properties"/>
</beans>
```

Here are a few good blog posts that explain how this works in more detail:

- [SPRING 3.1 M1: UNIFIED PROPERTY MANAGEMENT](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/)
- [USING CLOUD FOUNDRY SERVICES WITH SPRING: PART 4 – SPRING PROFILES](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/11/10/using-cloud-foundry-services-with-spring-part-4-%E2%80%93-spring-profiles/)

Comment: Excellent! Just what I needed! Thanks a lot Scott!